# Screen Time fails to set limit for some apps and the total screen time!

Tags: ios, bug

I am using iOS 14.3 but I have found Screen Time has a such serious bug in all iOS versions. This is my screen time rule: All Apps for 35 min and Games 15 min

[image: Screen Time Rules]

But it fails to work at all. For example, see the stats for today, **4 hours and 50 minutes**! **Games 2h 5m** !!

[image: Screen time stats]

And even screen time is kicking in (see the sandglass icon on most app), it fails to work on 2 specific apps, Bilibili & Chrome, no sandglass icon on them and I can indeed open them!

[image: Screen time fails]

I confirm I didn't add these 2 apps into **Always Allowed**

So to me this is really a serious bug!

Has anyone had any experience with this ?

[image: Always Allowed]